# Модальное окно bootstrap в мобильных браузерах

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется проблема отображения модального окна, созданного с использованием фрэймворка bootstrap, в мобильных браузерах.

То есть, в браузерах на компьютерах отображение модальных окон корректно, но, в мобильных версиях браузера, поверх модального окна всплывает какой-то, блокирующий весь доступ к сайту, блок.

Отследить, что это не получается так, как нет возможности просмотреть разметку в телефоне (либо я пока не нашёл способ).

В чём может быть проблема и где можно тестировать работу сайтов для телефонов (именно телефонов, а не проверять адаптивность вёрстки)?

Comment: Тестировать можно в браузере google chrome 100%. Режим разработчика -> иконка телефона и выбор устройства (там сориентируешься).
И желательно привести код, чтобы отвечающим было проще дать ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Сам сайт в недоработанном состоянии находится по адресу http://rehabilitation.by

Comment: Ещё одна особенность, что модальное окно нормально работает на симуляторе laptop, но на телефонах не работает.

Comment: окно, закрывающее все вокруг - это div с классом "modal-backdrop fade in"

Comment: Попробуйте media-запросами убирать это окно на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Вашем [сайте](http://rehabilitation.by/) в мобильной версии закрывает все окно блок:

```
 <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

Почему так происходит - непонятно, в весь код лезть не охота.


Бороться с этим можно след. образом:

 1) Удалить вовсе это блок ;) 
2) Добавить media-queries запрос, где на мобильной версии окно будет

```
 display:none
```

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, за участие. Основная проблема была в определении инструментария для тестирования сайта на мобильных платформах. А решение как всегда простое и находится рядом.